# BeautifulSoup returns all links, rather than the first link

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href=""> Text </a>
            <a href=""> Text </a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href=""> Text </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <a href=""> Text </a>
        </td>
        <td>
        <a href=""> Text </a>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to get the first link from each `td` element. I tried to achieve that with the following code:

```
website_data.select("tr td a")
```

However, this gives me all the `a` elements inside of a `td` element.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: `[i['href'] for i in website_data.select("tr td a")]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the first child a tag then you can use a:nth-child(1) to do this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html ='''<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="link1"> Text1 </a> <a href="link2"> Text2 </a></td>
                    <td><a href="link1"> Text1 </a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="link1"> Text1 </a> <a href="link2"> Text2 </a></td>
                    <td><a href="link1"> Text1 </a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
'''

soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
print([(i.text, i['href']) for i in soup.select('td a:nth-child(1)')])
```

Answer (score 0):

IF `website_data` is a `BeautifulSoup` object then you can try the following:

```
[td_element.find('a', href=True)['href'] for td_element in website_data.find_all('td')]
```

Comment: Thank you. Tomorrow I will try it with this and when it works I will Accept your Answer